# String class in salesforce

Tags: apex

Difference between between

1. `String s=new String('salesforce');`
2. `String s='salesforce';`

Why first statement is invalid in salesforce??

Answer (score 5):

In Java (the language upon which Apex is based) there is a difference in terms of where that String gets stored in the [String literal pool](http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/what-is-string-literal-pool/3).  Apex simply disallows the use of the constructor so that all strings are stored in a pool.  This has a variety of implications in terms of memory storage and security, which is why (I suspect) Apex only allows the latter and not the former.